# 000WebHost error using `serialize()` in constant definition

Tags: constants, web-hosting

I have this line inside a php file that I'm using on a website uploaded on 000WebHost:

```
define('ACCEPTED_OPERATORS' ,serialize([ ">=", "<=", ">", "<", "=", "%" ]));
```

the problem is the website is throwing this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'' in /home...` .
May I assume they don't accept functions as part of constant definition? I need that to make editing human-friendly(if there will be changes), because to change something in a serialized string is not nice for the eye.

Any advice here?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: they don't support array like `[elem1, elem2,]`, instead you have to do it strictly php-way: `Array(elem1, elem2)`.